# Using jQueryUI to get boolean from user

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, callback

I'm writing some form validation functions, and I've decided to go with jQueryUI for prompting the user because of flexibility.

There is a slight problem tho. I want my functions to return an array which consists of a boolean and a string for my error reporting system. JQueryUI dialogs are asynchronous which means the browser won't hang and wait for a return value as the native prompt() would.

Here is some sample code:

Validator function:

```
function verifyTOS_PVM_v2()
{
    verifyTOS_PVM_v2_callback = '';
    if(!empty($('#inputPVM').val())) {
        $('#inputPVM').val(date('d.m.Y', parseFinnishDate($('#inputPVM').val())));
        val = $('#inputPVM').val()
        date = parseFinnishDate($('#inputPVM').val());
        today = today();
        diff = Math.floor((date - today)/60/60/24);
        if(diff <= -14)
        {
            buttons = 
                [
                    {
                        text:"Kyllä",
                        click:function()
                        {
                            $(this).dialog('destroy');
                            verifyTOS_PVM_v2_callback = "Kyllä"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        text:"Ei",
                        click:function()
                        {
                            $(this).dialog('destroy');
                            verifyTOS_PVM_v2_callback = "Ei"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            jQueryPrompt('Message', 'Koskien päivämäärää...', 400, buttons);
            while(verifyTOS_PVM_v2_callback != "Kyllä" && verifyTOS_PVM_v2_callback != "Ei")
            {
                setTimeout('i = i + 1', 50)
            }
            res = verifyTOS_PVM_v2_callback;
            if(res == "Kyllä")
            {
                error_occured = 2;
                error = 'Message'
            }
            else
            {
                error_occured = 1;
                error = 'Message'
            }
        }
    } else {
        error_occurred = 1;
        error = "Message";
    }
    reterr[0] = error_occurred;
    reterr[1] = error;
    return reterr;
}
```

Prompt function:

```
function jQueryPrompt(msg, title, width, buttons)
{
    $('body').append('<div id="jQueryPromptHost"></div>');
    $('#jQueryPromptHost').append(msg);
    $('#jQueryPromptHost').dialog({
        title: title,
        resizable: false,
        width: width,
        daraggable: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: buttons
    })
}
```

I have tried polling for a variable and that failed miserably (firefox just hanged and took more memory for itself...)

Do you have any suggestions?

Regards,

Akke

EDIT:

I have picked another approach to this problem. I marked the closest solution as the answer, in case someone else picks his approach. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `click` event handler simply call a function instead of assigning a value.

```
buttons = [
    {
        text:"Kyllä",
        click: function() {
            $(this).dialog('destroy');
            handleButtonClick("Kyllä");
            //verifyTOS_PVM_v2_callback = "Kyllä"
        }
    },
    {
        text:"Ei",
        click: function() {
            $(this).dialog('destroy');
            handleButtonClick("Ei");
            //verifyTOS_PVM_v2_callback = "Ei"
        }
    }
]

//Somewhere else in the code
var handleButtonClick = function(value) {
    if (value == "Kyllä") {
        ...
    } else if (value == "Ei") {
        ...
    }
};
```

Comment: Oh, and I can put that into the function? Would you mind explaining why you assigned the function to a var?

Comment: Yes.  Functions are first class citizens in JavaScript.  Meaning, they can be assigned to variables and passed as parameters like strings, numbers, etc.  The ```function foo() {}``` syntax is simply shorthand for ```var foo = function() {}```, to the interpreter they're the same thing.

Comment: That explains why the javascript console outputs function foos source when I execute foo. That also explains why I have had MAJOR problems today having functions with same names as variables (Type error: date is not a function) :)

Answer (score 1):

while loop is locking, you can not use it.

Going to have to break up the function into two parts. First part is code before you call the dialog, second part is the part after the dialog. The dialog button clicks call the second function.

If the code has to be synchronous, you are sort of out of luck and stuck with the ugly window.prompt.

Comment: Well, is there any way to have multiple validators (one for each field) with this kind of input and/or async AJAX that all return to a central function? It can't be impossible...

Comment: You can queue up all of the functions and wait for them all to come back and than go off to the next step. jQuery has that all built in.

Comment: Would you happen to have some kind of an example or something..?